# How do I make MPC show forced subtitles?

Tags: video, subtitles, matroska, video-playback, media-player-classic

There is `Home Cinema` video player, installed directly from its site.

And it can show any other subtitles in a MKV video file, but it not showing the forced ones. I can select them, but there is just no text on the screen.

I have tried different rendering engines as well as different video filters or splitters I have defaultly installed along with the player, still nothing.

What should I do?

Comment: If you're using .srt files you just need to make sure that they have the same name as the associated movie and they exist in the same folder.

Comment: By forced ones what do you mean?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard by forced I mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtitle_(captioning)#Categories).

Comment: @yassarikhan786 It is built-in subs with additional "forced" flag set to true, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best answer I can give you are the bug reports I found while searching this:

[#2166 - MKV Default and Forced Subtitle Track Not Turned On](https://trac.mpc-hc.org/ticket/2166)

It seems as there is still no answer, and it is ongoing for some time. My advice would be to use another player for viewing the files with forced subtitles.